# future_row = {executor.submit(self.myjob, v): v for i in range(n_data)}

Tags: python, expression

I found some **python** code through the Internet
and I can't not understand the expression it means
May I ask for some help here?

> future_row = {executor.submit(self.myjob, v): v for i in
>   range(n_data)}

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take the time to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This piece of code is a [dictionary comprehension](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-dictionary-comprehension) that is equivalent to:

```
future_row = {}
for i in range(n_data):
    future_row[executor.submit(self.myjob, v)] = v
```

Answer (score 0):

This expression will return a dictionary "future_row" whose keys are [concurrent.futures.Future](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future) objects and whose values are the elements of a sequence of arguments, v in range(n_data). Each v in range n_data will be submitted to an [executor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor) whose future results stored in the keys of "future_row" will eventually contain the value of self.myjob(v) for a particular v.

To collect the results of the futures that are the keys in future_row, you will need to await them using something like [concurrent.futures.wait](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.wait).

```
finished, pending = concurrent.futures.wait(future_row.keys())
```